# How to connect to a VPN/Proxy server via Python?

Tags: python, proxy, routes, vpn

Okay so i know that you can route web-requests through a proxy in Python, is there any way to route ALL traffic from your system through a server. Much like a VPN client such as Hotspot Shield or CyberGhost, but a custom-build client using the Python language?

Any links/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is: network routing is managed by OS and could be managed by other utilities, like `iptables`. Adding such capabilities to standard libraries is out of the scope of programming language. So, what you are probably looking for is a binding of a VPN library (e.g. libpptp) or making syscalls in Cython, which is not much different than writing in C.

Comment: So it would be completely impractical and borderline impossible to do it in the Python language? And would be more-so practical to attempt this in the C language?

Comment: @MrHex Yes, exactly

Comment: Thank you very much for the response :)